# How to include external static files in Angular application

Tags: angular, file

In my angular project, I need to include external  .htm files that needs to displayed as a header.
These files are completely outside of my angular project and they are static files.

Static files are like:
c:\mydivision\myteam\global.htm
c:\mydivision\myteam\header.htm

I am not able to refer them or include them in my app.component.html.
When deployed to server , the file paths will be
root\mydivision\myteam\global.htm
root\mydivision\myteam\header.htm

I do Include these files:
Option 1: Create a simple web project of those static files, build that as war file and include that war in node-modules

Is option 1 the only way, or is there an other way.

Comment: If you do not want to build them but simply want them to be included in your deployment then include them as assets in your `angular.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question, you can not achieve this at all. Angular HTML templates are not plain HTML, they are compiled into JavaScript before being executed in the browser. Since the javascript is executed in the browser (no server side) HTML can not be included the way you describe it.